# Tensorflow graph use questions

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I've trained a little dataset of car with inception.
Now, I Have a meta file, a ckpt file then a pbtxt file.
And now I want to know how to make prediction with it..

I tried to use freeze_graph.py but it ask an output_node_names parameter and I absolutely don't know what it could be.

If you know how I could use my ckpt/meta/pbtxt to do prediction or how to freeze my graph with freeze_graph to use classify.py I would be very thanksful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to answer the question without more details about the code you used to generate the graph. More generally, there is a tutorial on retraining Inception for a new dataset here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html that you may find helpful.

Comment: Hi Peter,
To generate the graph, I just used :
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph.as_graph_def(), FLAGS.train_dir, 'input_graph_binary' + str(step)+ '.pb', as_text=False)
I placed it below the call to saver.save
Thanks for your help

Comment: Sure, but I would need more context than that. tf.train.write_graph() saves the graph, but it doesn't say anything about the structure of the graph, such as the node names. Are you modifying an existing example?

Comment: Oh sorry..
In fact, I added this line in inception_train.py ( You can find this here : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception/inception)
So, in out, I have the model.ckpt and the graph.
Once I did that, I tried to freeze it with freeze_graph.py (Here : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py)

But, unfortunately, it don't accept any output_nodes. Maybe I do a mistake ?
Because I test with : final_result/softmax:0/ etc... But nothing work..